# Simplifying code

Tags: php, html, css

I have this piece of code which changes the colour of a HTML cell based on the Value. Its function is to display if the slots (out of 3) are full/empty/have space.

I have only included one of the IF statements for 9AM. I have duplicated and altered the code for each time frame, so 10Am, 11AM, 12PM etc.. Which takes up a lot of lines of code and doesn't look very good.

Is there are a way to simplify this for all columns in my table?

Comment: Use an array with the times and loop over them in a foreach or While loop. Then parameterize your code to simplify it...

Comment: You can use:

elif
instead of

else if

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to simplify the code, try to use this:

```
$result = mysql_query($query); if(!$result) { die("MySQL query failed: " . mysql_error()); } else{ print ''; print ""; while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result,MYSQL_ASSOC)) { if(strpos($row['9AM'], '(3)')) { $nineam="#00FF00"; } else if (empty($row['9AM'])){ $nineam = ""; } else if (strpos($row['9AM'], '(1)')){ $nineam ="#00FF00"; } else if (strpos($row['9AM'], '(2)')){ $nineam ="#00FF00"; } else if (strpos($row['9AM'], '(0)')){ $nineam ="#FF0000"; } print " ";
<table>
    <tr>
        <td><strong>May</strong></td>
        <td><strong>9AM</strong></td>
        <td><strong>10AM</strong></td>
        <td><strong>11AM</strong></td>
        <td><strong>12PM</strong></td>
        <td><strong>13PM</strong></td>
        <td><strong>14PM</strong></td>
        <td><strong>15PM</strong></td>
        <td><strong>16PM</strong></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>{$row['Day']}</td>
        <td bgcolor="\&quot;$nineam\&quot;">{$row['9AM']}</td>
        <td bgcolor="\&quot;$tenam\&quot;">{$row['10AM']}</td>
        <td bgcolor="\&quot;$elevenam\&quot;">{$row['11AM']}</td>
        <td bgcolor="\&quot;$twelvpm\&quot;">{$row['12PM']}</td>
        <td bgcolor="\&quot;$onepm\&quot;">{$row['13PM']}</td>
        <td bgcolor="\&quot;$twopm\&quot;">{$row['14PM']}</td>
        <td>{$row['15PM']}</td>
        <td>{$row['16PM']}</td>
    </tr>
```

Comment: Don't you need `echo()` to actually show the variables though?